# How to update tree view in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

Here is my SQL Server table

```
ID      Job                       ParentID    MyTeam
1       CEO                       NULL        
2       CFO                       1
3       CTO                       1
4       CMO                       1
5       Accounting Manager        2
6       Payroll Manager           2
7       Data Manager              3
8       Software Manager          3
9       Data Analyst              7
10      Data Engineer             7
```

I need to fill the MyTeam field this way

each job will have all people that job managing

**CEO's** team will be `CEO, CFO, CTO, CMO, Accounting Manager, Payroll Manager, Data Manager, Software Manager, Data Analyst, Data Engineer`

**CFO's** team will be `CFO, Accounting Manager, Payroll Manager`

**CTO's** team will be  `CTO, Data Manager, Software Manager, Data Analyst, Data Engineer`

I built a loop on this data and contacted each job to its parent and so on

but this is too slow

Is there a faster one update statement to do that fast

Comment: @KenWhite no it does not, it is different

Comment: @KenWhite it just return a list of the child records of a parent, does not concat for all or group by or update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE for this.

First, get all of the employees, and for each one get its child rows if any, using the recursion. Note that we have not made any loop checking here, the assumption is that there are no loops.

Then aggregate it by the top ID that you started with, and join it back to the main table.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT e.ID, e.Job, e.ID AS TopID
    FROM Employee e

    UNION ALL

    SELECT e.ID, e.Job, cte.TopID
    FROM cte
    JOIN Employee e ON e.ParentID = cte.ID
)
UPDATE e
SET MyTeam = grouped.Jobs
FROM Employee e
JOIN (
    SELECT
      cte.TopID,
      STRING_AGG(cte.Job, ', ') AS Jobs
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY
      cte.TopID
) grouped ON grouped.TopID = e.ID;
```

You can also enforce an ordering by calculating a `Level` column in the CTE

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT e.ID, e.Job, e.ID AS TopID, 1 AS Level
    FROM Employee e

    UNION ALL

    SELECT e.ID, e.Job, cte.TopID, cte.Level + 1
    FROM cte
    JOIN Employee e ON e.ParentID = cte.ID
)
UPDATE e
SET MyTeam = grouped.Jobs
FROM Employee e
JOIN (
    SELECT
      cte.TopID,
      STRING_AGG(cte.Job, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cte.Level) AS Jobs
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY
      cte.TopID
) grouped ON grouped.TopID = e.ID;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/z-7pcgJX)

Comment: Yep, this it literally the text book example for a recursive CTE use case.

Answer (score 1):

This approach uses a loop, but should be relatively fast

- It runs based on the number of levels in the jobs, rather than the individuals (so if you have 3 levels like here, it does 3 loops)
- The reads and calculations are very efficient - it doesn't need to do a lot of JOINs and sorting and table scans (other than the first)

There are examples of this running, with some extra reporting, in [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wyy777RL)

```
/*  Initial data setup  */

CREATE TABLE #Emps (ID int PRIMARY KEY, Job nvarchar(30), ParentID int);
INSERT INTO #Emps (ID, Job, ParentID) VALUES
(1,       N'CEO',                       NULL),
(2,       N'CFO',                       1),
(3,       N'CTO',                       1),
(4,       N'CMO',                       1),
(5,       N'Accounting Manager',        2),
(6,       N'Payroll Manager',           2),
(7,       N'Data Manager',              3),
(8,       N'Software Manager',          3),
(9,       N'Data Analyst',              7),
(10,      N'Data Engineer ',            7);

CREATE TABLE #EmpParents (RoundNum int, ID int, ParentID int, PRIMARY KEY (RoundNum, ID));
```

The data for each 'round' (e.g., iteration number in the loop) is inserted into the #EmpParents table.

The approach is to
a) First include the base job, and the parent job
b) Then for the parent job, identify their parents
Repeat b) until no more parent jobs are found.

The way it finds the 'parents of parents' is to look at the last 'round' in the loop to get the the parent ID for each job from that round; in the next round it uses these new parents to identify the next level of parents.

Note that I've done this with a WHILE loop because I think it's easier to read/understand. However, you could do this with a CURSOR or recursive CTE - but they are variations on a loop anyway.

```
/*  Data calculations - Find parents, and parents of parents  */

DECLARE @RoundNum int;     -- Used for counting what iteration we're up to
DECLARE @NumInserted int;  -- User for recording number of rows inserted

-- Insert initial data (own job and parent job)
INSERT INTO #EmpParents (RoundNum, ID, ParentID)
    SELECT  0, ID, ID
    FROM    #Emps
  UNION ALL
    SELECT  1, ID, ParentID
    FROM    #Emps
    WHERE   ParentID IS NOT NULL;

SET @NumInserted = @@ROWCOUNT;
SET @RoundNum = 1;

-- Add 'parents of parents' until no more found
WHILE @NumInserted > 0
    BEGIN

    SET @RoundNum += 1;

    INSERT INTO #EmpParents (RoundNum, ID, ParentID)
        SELECT  @RoundNum, #EmpParents.ID, #Emps.ParentID
        FROM    #EmpParents
                INNER JOIN #Emps ON #EmpParents.ParentID = #Emps.ID
        WHERE   #EmpParents.RoundNum = @RoundNum - 1
                AND #Emps.ParentID IS NOT NULL;

    SET @NumInserted = @@ROWCOUNT;

    END
```

In the final reporting, note that it uses the last column (ParentID) as the main column, and finds all the job IDs that correspond to it.

```
/*  Reporting  */

SELECT      ParentEmp.Job, STRING_AGG(TeamEmp.Job, ', ') AS Team
    FROM    #EmpParents
            INNER JOIN #Emps AS ParentEmp ON #EmpParents.ParentID = ParentEmp.ID
            INNER JOIN #Emps AS TeamEmp ON #EmpParents.ID = TeamEmp.ID
    GROUP BY #EmpParents.ParentID, ParentEmp.Job
    ORDER BY #EmpParents.ParentID;
```

Here are the results

```
Job                            Team
------------------------------ ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CEO                            CEO, CFO, CTO, CMO, Accounting Manager, Payroll Manager, Data Manager, Software Manager, Data Analyst, Data Engineer 
CFO                            Accounting Manager, Payroll Manager, CFO
CTO                            CTO, Data Manager, Software Manager, Data Analyst, Data Engineer 
CMO                            CMO
Accounting Manager             Accounting Manager
Payroll Manager                Payroll Manager
Data Manager                   Data Manager, Data Analyst, Data Engineer 
Software Manager               Software Manager
Data Analyst                   Data Analyst
Data Engineer                  Data Engineer
```

Final note: There is no error checking in this and assumes a hierarchical structure (e.g., you cannot have a loop of parents e.g., my subordinate is my boss' boss). You may want to put some error checking into the loop/etc to control for that. A simple one would be that if `RoundNum` gets to an impossibly impractical high number (e.g., 50) then it aborts with an error.